# service fabric unable to see container template in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-devops, azure-service-fabric

I am following instruction given in following link : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-containers#create-the-containerized-service-in-visual-studio

> The Service Fabric SDK and tools provide a service template to help you create a containerized application.
>
> 1. Start Visual Studio. Select **File** > **New** > **Project**.
> 2. Select **Service Fabric application**, name it "MyFirstContainer", and click **OK**.
> 3. Select **Container** from the list of **service templates**.
> 4. In **Image Name** enter "myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/helloworldapp", the image you pushed to your container repository.
>      Give your service a name, and click **OK**.

When I open visual studio community edition, I do not see any such template. This is what I see:

[image]

I have already installed Azure development components:

[image]

**How can I deploy container image on azure service fabric cluster?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that you perform the steps explained in the instructions. On you first screenshot it seems that you have selected **Service Fabric Application** on the left but that is just the most recent template that you have used.

On the right you then search for **container** but that will find all templates that contain the word **container**. You want to find the **Service Fabric Application** template (which happens to be the most recent template in your screenshot).

The *container* part is something you select to add a new service to your **Service Fabric Application** so it's not a Visual Studio project template but a Service Fabric service template. Here are som screenshots from my Visual Studio 2019 16.4.4:

Select the **Service Fabric Application** template and press **Next**:

[image: Screenshot of the Create a new project dialog box]

Name your project etc. and press **Create**:

[image: Screenshot of the dialog box used to create a new Service Fabric project]

Select **Container** in the **Hosted Containers and Applications** section of the service templates to add a service to your project and finalize the project creation process.

[image: Screenshot of the dialog box used to create a new Service Fabric service]

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio 2017 and later:

Open Visual Studio

Tools (On top bar menu)

Get Tools and Features (the installer will open to modify VS features)

Azure Development

select 'Service Fabric'

Confirm the changes and setup